# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'> ( need to take log)

Tags: python, json, excel, optimization, ipython

I an trying to take sum of a variable after taking log of it. Can you please guide me on below code?

```
data_size['Deal Size / Complexity Measure2']=pd.DataFrame.sum(math.log(data_size['Deal Size'])+data_size['Deal Complexity'])/100
```

I am not sure if i have entered correct as i am trying to covert excel code to Python--below is excel code which i am trying to convert.
=SUM(LOG(D2)+E2)/100

Comment: Maybe try to convert to float first?

Comment: sanc['Deal Size / Complexity Measure2']=pd.DataFrame.sum(math.log(float(sanc['Deal Size']))+float(sanc['Deal Complexity'])/100   - tried this- got another error--

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Looks soe brackets are missing, too

Comment: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing  ,       also please have a look at my code this is my first time i am trying to calculate log  :)

Comment: Looks some brackets are missing... check your brackets...

Comment: i checked again and looks my brackets are correct. don't you see any error in my code? Any other suggestion for alteration in syntex

Comment: Please update your original question with the modified code and the new error message. And please give the content of your two variables you are trying to convert...

Comment: Deal Size     Deal Complexity   
251,042    0.56
69,774   0.46
195,980  1.02
68,594  0.48
319,318 0.69
236,779 0.72
227,421 0.50
sanc['Deal Size / Complexity Measure2']=pd.DataFrame.sum(math.log(float(sanc['Deal Size']))+float(sanc['Deal Complexity'])/100   error- unexpected EOF while parsing          please let me know if you are not able to understand the data structure

Comment: Deal Size
251,042
69,774
195,980
68,594
319,318
236,779
227,421

Comment: You have 4 opening brackets in your expression, but only 3 closing bracket. One closing bracket is missing, hence the error.

Comment: Deal Complexity
0.56
0.46
1.02
0.48
0.69
0.72
0.50

Comment: new column name -- Win IBM GP

Comment: This does not help. Is that a single variable? A list? A dict? You should post `python` code here

Comment: excel code  which i am trying to convert to python    =SUM(LOG(Deal Size)+Deal Complexity)/100

Comment: Have you checked your brackets?

Comment: Yes Alex i did check,    After closing bracket i got below error       cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>      sanc['Deal Size / Complexity Measure2']=pd.DataFrame.sum(math.log(float(sanc['Deal Size']))+float(sanc['Deal Complexity']))/100

Comment: Probably because you can convert a single item to float, not a list or the like

Comment: so Alex being an expert do you have any solution for my question. I am sure there would be a solution to create a Data Frame or Series to float. or if you could try it in your system and check if it works. And the most important i want to thank you for being so quick and guiding me.

Comment: I have not worked with panda before (which I guess is 'pd'). I also do not know what the term `sanc['Deal Complexity']` exactly is. I guess a panda series or so? However, if I knew I could provide a solution in 1 minute

Comment: sanc- my data set name , Deal Size-variable name1, Deal Complexity- variable2  having values -251,042 0.56 respectively  and the excel code for which i need python is =SUM(LOG(D2)+E2)/100

Comment: when i run below syntax divided by 100 i get 4.528005 in all rows but as per excel i should get values like this , Deal Size / Complexity Measure 0.059620414 0.053064582 0.063106603 0.053142334 0.061977867 0.060964322

Comment: Alex we are very close to it . when i tried in excel now i get correct values but python shows same and very high unrealistic values in all rows. Please let me know when would you be available for chat

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sanc['Deal Size / Complexity Measure2'] = sum([(math.log(x)+y) for x,y in zip(sanc['Deal Size'],sanc['Deal Size'])])
```

Comment: when i gave upper syntax divided by 100 i get 4.528005 in all rows but as per excel i should get values like this ,   Deal Size / Complexity Measure
0.059620414
0.053064582
0.063106603
0.053142334
0.061977867
0.060964322